# why is justify-content: center; of my css code not working

Tags: html, css

I took this front end challenge from frontend mentor but I have been trying to move the card to the center of the screen but it looks like the **justify-content: center** isn't working for it. What should I do?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Outfit:wght@400;600&display=swap');

:root {
    --white: hsl(0,0%,100%);
    --lightgray: hsl(212,45%,89%);
    --grayishblue: hsl(220,15%,55%);
    --darkblue: hsl(218,44%,22%);
    font-family: outfit;
    font-size: 15px;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: var(--lightgray);
    font-family: 'outfit' sans-serif;
}

.card {
    background-color: white;
    max-width: 330px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding:15px;
    
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.qr-code {
    
    text-align: center;
    
}

h2 {
    color: var(--darkblue);
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Frontend Mentor | QR code component</title>

    <style>
        .attribution { font-size: 11px; text-align: center; }
        .attribution a { color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%); }
      </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="card">

       
            <img src="images/image-qr-code.png" alt="qr-code">
            <div class="qr-code">
            <h2>Improve Your front-end skills by building projects</h2>
            <p>Scan the QR code to visit Frontend Mentor your coding skills to the next level</p>
        </div>
        
        
    </div>
    <div class="attribution">
        Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>. 
        Coded by <a href="#">Your Name Here</a>.
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is what I'm going for:
I took this front end challenge from frontend mentor but I have been trying to move the card to the center of the screen but it looks like the **justify-content: center** isn't working for it. What should I do ?

[image: intended outcome]

Comment: Do you want to center vertically?

Answer (score 4):

If you look up the definition for `justify-content` (like w3schools):

> The `justify-content` property aligns the flexible container's items
> when the items do not use all available space on the main-axis
> (horizontally).

Note that it says the **flexible container's items**, meaning that applying the `justify-content` property is applied to the container's children.

It seems that what you've done is apply the `justify-content: center` property on the `.card` element - referring to the definition above, this means that the children of the `.card` element will be centered, not `.card` itself.

ps. also important to note that the definition says **horizontally**

Comment: Very good and complete explanations:)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want the card to be in the center of the screen, you need a wrapper around it.
You can also make body a flexbox, but I'm not in favor of doing that.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Outfit:wght@400;600&display=swap');
:root {
  --white: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  --lightgray: hsl(212, 45%, 89%);
  --grayishblue: hsl(220, 15%, 55%);
  --darkblue: hsl(218, 44%, 22%);
  font-family: outfit;
  font-size: 15px;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--lightgray);
  font-family: 'outfit' sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card {
  background-color: white;
  max-width: 330px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.attribution {
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
}

.attribution a {
  color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%);
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.qr-code {
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  color: var(--darkblue);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="images/image-qr-code.png" alt="qr-code">
    <div class="qr-code">
      <h2>Improve Your front-end skills by building projects</h2>
      <p>Scan the QR code to visit Frontend Mentor your coding skills to the next level</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="attribution">
    Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>. Coded by <a href="#">Your Name Here</a>.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Gerard's answer is very good. One other way of centering a div in the body is using from below code:

```
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

**So** wrap your code in a `container`, then add the above CSS to that.

**Edit:** Your `.card` is centralized horizontally with `margin: 0 auto`. in my answer no need to do it.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Outfit:wght@400;600&display=swap');

:root {
    --white: hsl(0,0%,100%);
    --lightgray: hsl(212,45%,89%);
    --grayishblue: hsl(220,15%,55%);
    --darkblue: hsl(218,44%,22%);
    font-family: outfit;
    font-size: 15px;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: var(--lightgray);
    font-family: 'outfit' sans-serif;
}

.container{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.card {
    background-color: white;
    max-width: 330px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding:15px;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.qr-code {
    
    text-align: center;
    
}

h2 {
    color: var(--darkblue);
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Frontend Mentor | QR code component</title>

    <style>
        .attribution { font-size: 11px; text-align: center; }
        .attribution a { color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%); }
      </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card">
            <img src="images/image-qr-code.png" alt="qr-code">
            <div class="qr-code">
            <h2>Improve Your front-end skills by building projects</h2>
            <p>Scan the QR code to visit Frontend Mentor your coding skills to the next level</p>
            </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="attribution">
        Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>. 
        Coded by <a href="#">Your Name Here</a>.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```